# Chrome autostart on ubuntu

Tags: autostart

I have recently installed Ubuntu on my PC, but I can't understand how to manage the applications -- as an example, I'm trying to get Chrome to autostart. 
I can start Chrome manually, but I'm not able to find the correct exe (to make it autostart).  How can I make this work?

Comment: has auto start and chrome in title, no mention of either in body, talks of managing applications, tagged ubuntu-one, man, this question confuses me, too much

Comment: Can you be a little more clear in stating what you want to do?

Comment: It's true... too confusing. At least, I answered something :)

Comment: @Alvar  I'd say give the OP a chance to respond.  (And if I understand the question correctly, then espectall123 has answered it.)

Answer (score 22):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

So... you're really new to Ubuntu! I should say you two things:

1. Don't worry about finding EXEs, they don't exist.
2. Even without EXEs, you're still able to autostart an app when logging in.

If you want to autostart Chrome when logging in, follow this steps:

- Go to the Dash, and open Startup Application Preferences. It should appear a window like this:

[image: Startup Apps!]

- Press the "Add" button.
- In the "Command" field, paste the following text: `google-chrome`. Put what you want in "Name" and "Comment". Press Save.

Ready! Now every time Ubuntu boots, you'll be able to directly browse from Chrome :)

Comment: I agree with your interpretation of what he asked and think you did a good job answering what his question likely was.  One suggestion though, maybe include instructions on how to install chrome/note the difference between chrome and chromium, in case it is not already installed.

Comment: Or if you have chromium, you may use `chromium-browser` as your command.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu and related (Unix/Linux/BSD) systems don't typically designate applications with the `.exe` extensions.   (They can be interpreted by the system according to file associations, MIME types, format of the file, and so on.)

Executable files (that is, applications) are usually found in `bin` directories.  (There are other questions and references that go into detail on the where and why.)

There are some handy commands to find these files, but in many cases, the system already knows where there are -- if you can execute google-chrome manually, it is probably already in a place (path) that Ubuntu knows about, so just adding the name of the application (google-chrome) in something like the startup menu is sufficient.